# Is image of dot product on closed and convex set closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The problem statement is:

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed and convex. Fixing $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is $p \cdot X = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} : y = p \cdot x \text{, for some } x \in X \}$ a closed set?

My intuition suggests that it would indeed be a closed set. If $X$ is assumed to be bounded, then it is continuous image of a compact set. The problem is I can't seem to find a rigorous way to explain what happens if $X$ is not bounded. Because $p$ is fixed and not allowed to depend on the input vector $x \in X$, I would think there would not be any problems like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147879/continuous-functions-do-not-necessarily-map-closed-sets-to-closed-sets). Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be closed

$$X=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\,:\, xy\ge1\wedge x>0\}\\ p=(1,0)\\p\cdot X=(0,+\infty)$$

**Geometrically:** $X$ is the slice of half-plane that's over the hyperbola $y=\frac1x$ for positive $x$. Scalar product by $p$ yields the $x$-component, hence $p\cdot X$ is the domain of $f$.

Comment: Oh, right. I guess every example of X that I was thinking of was much nicer than that. Thanks!

Comment: One might add that the assertion holds, if $X$ is additionally assumed to be bounded (via a compactness argument).

Comment: @gerw The OP already knows that. However, in the [related questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908121/continuous-linear-image-of-closed-bounded-and-convex-set-of-a-hilbert-space-is?rq=1) there is an interesting extension of "$X$ closed bounded$\Rightarrow$ $p\cdot X$ closed" in the case of Hilbert spaces.